# Python correlation coefficient for 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to compute a correlation coefficient for a moving window over a 3D array? When I run:

```
Import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import generic_filter

arr_3d = np.dstack((data1,data2))

def function(arr_3d):
    return np.corrcoef(arr_3d[:,:,0],arr_3d[:,:,1])

gen_filt = generic_filter(arr_3d, function, footprint=np.ones((7,7,2)), mode='nearest')
```

The error I keep getting is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "correlate.py", line 251, in <module>
    plot_data()
  File "correlate.py", line 219, in plot_data
    gen_filt = generic_filter(arr_3d,function,footprint=np.ones((35,35,2)),mode='nearest')
  File "/apps/python/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/filters.py", line 1245, in generic_filter
    cval, origins, extra_arguments, extra_keywords)
  File "correlate.py", line 217, in function
    return np.corrcoef(arr_3d[:,:,0],arr_3d[:,:,1])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Here's an example of what some of the data looks like. The dstack function seems to successfully create the 3D array.

```
data1 = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(10,10))
data2 = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(10,10))

arr_3d = np.dstack((x,y))
print(arr_3d.shape)

(10, 10, 2)
```

I didn't include the arr_3d here but after looking at it it appeared to be correctly formatted.

Comment: Please print it out the full stack of error. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for editing the post. Are you sure `arr_3d` is actually 3d? Could you please print out its shape using `arr_3d.shape`? Without the data it is hard to debug. maybe a toy example of data for `data1` and `data2` will help.

Comment: The dstack seems to make the 3d array. I've included a little example data. I think the issue may be with np.corrcoef creating a 2d array but the arr_3d and footprint are 3d but Im not sure.

Comment: It does not work because the function in generic_filter must return a scalar for a pair of inputs by assigned filter. What is it that you are trying to achieve? I think this use of generic_filter is not the correct way to go. Maybe you can elaborate on your original problem and we can help better. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a moving window correlation using a different method:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

#this is your window shape
window = (7,7,2)
windows = view_as_windows(arr_3d, window).reshape(-1, *window)
window_corr = np.array([np.corrcoef(item[:,:,0], item[:,:,1]) for item in windows])
```

You can also avoid for loop at a cost of calculating the correlation of all windows, but I think looping is faster in this case (unless there is a better vectorized way of correlation between elements of a 3D array)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This has seemed to work well. Do you know how this function deals with edges? 'scipy.ndimage.generic_filter' has different options to deal with boundaries, does view_as_windows automatically do this? Also, the shape of arr_3d is (148,334,2) but the shape of window_corr is (34200, 70, 70). Why is this?

Comment: Here is the doc for it: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html . How do you want to deal with the edges? and what is your original array shape and what is your window size? without those information, the shapes you are referring to are meaningless.